# Shopify Admin API - add sales channel to product

Tags: shopify

I have some products that I want to add them a sale channel using Shopify API, and not ask the user to do that manually from Shopify dashboard.

any way to do that?

Comment: https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/sales-channels

Comment: I check all of these API's. none of them allows adding sales channel to product

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [publishable publish mutation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-07/mutations/publishablePublish).